# Suggest leaving a templated comment when flagging a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flagging, comments

When flagging a question to be closed, migrated et cetera, I often want to leave comment with a suggestion for the OP about how to improve their question or where it would be more appropriate to ask.

I wish there was an option on the flag dialog à la "Do you want to leave a comment notifying the OP of this flag?". It could contain a **kindly worded comment template** to make it easier for the flagger  and more helpful for the OP.

Comment: The new review offers some canned comments, so [status-completed] (sorts of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'd definitely use it :)

Tailored comments would be preferable, and the user script Anna shared is more or less the feature as I want it, but I think there would be some value in assembling a list of template comments to better guide users write helpful comments (and use in the script).

I'm always struggling with my English, several of my comments have been misunderstood as snarky, my syntax and spelling may be good, but more often than not my comments are verbatim translations of what I'm thinking in Greek, and that doesn't always work.

I usually go one of three ways:

- Down / close vote with no comment (just won't bother),
- Copy someone else's comment, with slight adjustments,
- Comment with my broken English and hope for the best :)

In short, I have to think, even slightly, and I would love it if I didn't have to think, at all. Comment wars are more than usual, and template comments could help, and get more users to participate. There's one example of an auto generated comment, the one that appears when a possible duplicate vote is cast.

I'm playing around with the script now, and it seems more than enough. I'll try and compile a list of comments and share at some point, hope others will use / improve them.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it really needs a separate feature, since it's pretty easy to just click "add comment" after you flag.

You can store and customize comments you leave most often using [this user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), although I recommend still tailoring comments to the question when needed/possible.

We could probably come up with the most common comments that apply to questions erroneously posted to Programmers (e.g. career advice) and share those here on meta to help others set up their script as well.

Comment: I was unaware of these user scripts. Thank you for sharing. I suppose such a script plus a bunch of standard templates for the most common cases would do 99% of what I was trying to accomplish with my feature suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with adding your comment via the usual "add comment" link and then voting/closing/flagging?

Adding an extra, optional, step into these actions would be making the workflow more complicated.